# No such table - Discord.py - Sqlite3 database error

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

I'm in the process of making a bot that has some different functions. The bot is able to register when someone checks in and checks out. When someone checks out it adds +1 to a database and saves it.

I've run into the problem that it won't connect to my database. Have tried using "Import os" and doing this by through with couldn't get it to work. I have made a file called "attendance.db" out in my folder where I also have my python file. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so does anyone know how I can fix my problem?

```
import discord
import sqlite3

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!check-in'):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('attendance.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute('SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE user_id = ? AND checked_in = 1', (message.author.id,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result:
            await message.channel.send('You are already checked in!')
        else:
            c.execute('INSERT INTO attendance (user_id, checked_in) VALUES (?, 1)', (message.author.id,))
            conn.commit()
            await message.channel.send('You are now checked in!')

        conn.close()

    if message.content.startswith('!check-out'):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('attendance.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute('SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE user_id = ? AND checked_in = 1', (message.author.id,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result:
            c.execute('UPDATE attendance SET checked_in = 0 WHERE user_id = ?', (message.author.id,))
            c.execute('UPDATE stats SET num_checked_out = num_checked_out + 1 WHERE id = 1')
            conn.commit()
            await message.channel.send('You are now checked out!')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You are not checked in!')

        conn.close()

    if message.content.startswith('!info'):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('attendance.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute('SELECT num_checked_out FROM stats WHERE id = 1')
        num_checked_out = c.fetchone()[0]

        await message.channel.send('{} users have checked out.'.format(num_checked_out))

        conn.close()
```

Getting this error in my terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\rober\Desktop\discord\main.py", line 24, in on_message
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE user_id = ? AND checked_in = 1', (message.author.id,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: attendance
```

Comment: You need to create a table in your database first.

Comment: Wdym? I got a file called ``attendance.db`` in my folder

Comment: That is a database, not a table. In SQL, databases are collections of tables. You need to create a table in your database first.